# Can't Open Ports Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, google-compute-engine, windows-firewall, tightvnc

I'm trying to get TightVNC to remote into my Server 2016 instance.  I have the VNC Server listening on 5901.  I've created a firewall rule in the instance itself, and on my VPC network firewall rules page.  Netstat -an doesn't show 5901 as listening.  I'm honestly at a loss.

Here's my `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` response (tight-vnc is the rule I'm working on):

```
NAME                       NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
board-login-test-tcp-80    default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80                              False
default-allow-http         default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80                              False
default-allow-https        default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443                             False
default-allow-icmp         default  INGRESS    65534     icmp                                False
default-allow-internal     default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp        False
default-allow-rdp          default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389                            False
default-allow-ssh          default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22                              False
tcp-5900                   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5900                            False
tight-vnc                  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5901                            False
```

And here's the output for `gcloud compute firewall-rules describe tight-vnc:`

```
allowed:
- IPProtocol: tcp
  ports:
  - '5901'
creationTimestamp: '2019-02-19T01:27:40.816-08:00'
description: ''
direction: INGRESS
disabled: false
id: '5356307468551353059'
kind: compute#firewall
logConfig:
  enable: false
name: tight-vnc
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/tkh-sales-and-service/global/networks/default
priority: 1000
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/tkh-sales-and-service/global/firewalls/tight-vnc
sourceRanges:
- 0.0.0.0/0
targetTags:
- instance-1
```

I don't have a lot of experience so I may be missing something stupid.

Comment: ```Netstat -an doesn't show 5901 as listening.``` that's a problem. Did you run tightvncserver at least once?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the port isn't serving traffic, I would try to restart the service or confirm that's running correctly, if you are following any guide please let me know.